# Fancybox Loading On Page Start not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I am having a Fancybox load as soon as the page loads. Works fine in FF but it does not work in IE and I am unsure as why. I get no errors in IE when the page loads. It just doesn't work.

**Script for Fancybox**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){

        Engine.Initialize();  //Not Fancybox - Loads different Script

$j("#start").fancybox({
    'padding' : 0
});
});
</script>
```

**HTML for Fancybox**

```
<div class="hide">
<a href="#welcome" id="start"></a>
    <img src="/Images/skin/spacer1x1.png" onload="$j('#start').trigger('click');" />  
    <img src="/Images/start/start.png" alt="PLEASE VIEW PAGE WITH IMAGES ON" border="0" usemap="#welcomeMap" id="welcome" style="width:700px; height:600px;" />
    <map name="welcomeMap" id="welcomeMap">
      <area shape="rect" coords="31,505,347,538" href="/examples/month-1/" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="512,506,660,542" href="javascript:$j.fancybox.close();" alt="Close" />
    </map>
</div>
```

Not sure why it does not work in IE. Is it the onload to "trigger" the click to launch the Fancybox?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: Onload #start triggers click of link with the id of start then when that link is clicked the img with the id of welcome will load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in IE it is trying to redirect to href on click of anchor. Can you try this.

```
$j("#start").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $j(this.href).fancybox({
      'padding' : 0
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that replacing the fancybox code with the one you provided. It did not work. It also stopped it working in FF. Not sure if I did something wrong?

Comment: Please try my edited answer, by mistake I use `$` instead of `$j` since you have used set noconflict.

Comment: It just doesn't work. There are no errors. Here is the page if that would help: http://bit.ly/nQdjXZ

Comment: Where is the link on the page?

Comment: The link is hidden on the page and should be triggered when the page loads

Comment: I saw it working, on page load execute this `$j("#start").click();` in console

Comment: You need to trigger the click event on page load in order to execute it

Comment: Thanks, that works! Well, almost, it works in IE 8+ but not in 7 (didn't try 6) but it also works in the other browsers. Thanks for your help. If you have thoughts on 7 would like to hear them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my project I'm using the following code:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#status-link").fancybox(
                 { 'modal': true }
            );
            $("#status-link").trigger('click');
        });
    </script>
<a id="status-link" href="test.aspx" style="visibility: hidden"</a>
```

Works for me in IE7/8. You can try something like this.